# More Bash Choice Menu Options

Tags: bash

How can I have more options to answer this?

```
while [ "$yn" != "Yes" ]; do
 echo "Please enter your Host Name"
 read hname
 echo "You have entered $hname, is this correct? (Yes or No)"
  read yn
done
sh runscript.sh
```

Would like to answer with "Yes" "yes" "Y" or "y", how can this be done?
Thanks in Advance,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Think this works best:

```
while [[ "$yn" != "Yes" && "$yn" != "Y" && "$yn" != "y" && "$yn" != "yes" ]]; do
```

Yay!

Answer (score 6):

```
while [ -z "$yn" ]
do
    read -p "Please enter your Host Name" hname
    read -p "You have entered $hname, is this correct? (Yes or No)" yn
    case $yn in
        Y|y|Yes|yes);;    # this is a no-op
        *) unset yn;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As pretty much any other language, Bash has logical operators. You can create something like this with Bash (this is pseudo-code):

```
If answer equals "Yes", or answer equals "yes":
   bla bla
```

I recommend you look up a Bash tutorial, you'll find that and much more!
Cheers.